# How to extract data from array instead of Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

How to correctly extract data from array instead of [Object]

apiClient

```js
export interface apiRequest {
  locations: LocationOptions[];

}
interface FOLocations {
  locationId: number;
}

interface LocationResult {
  location: FOLocations[];
  cityName: string;
}

export const locationCheck = async (
  apiKey: string,
  payload: apiRequest
): Promise<LocationResult[]> => {
  let response = await axios.post<LocationResult[]>(
    `api...`,
    payload
  );
  return response.data;
```

runCode

```js
  const locationPayload : apiRequest = {
      locations:[{ cityName: "London"},{cityName: "New York"},{cityName: "Paris"}],
    };
    const locationResponse = await locationCheck(apiKey,locationPayload);
    const locationResponseRes =  locationResponse;
    console.log(locationResponseRes);
```

I need to get to values locationResponseRes.cityName .
Actual output :

```
[
  {
    location: { locationId: 1, address: [Object] },
    deliveryOptions: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    location: { locationId: 2,},
    cityName: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
{
  "location": {
    "locationId": 1,
    cityName: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

Expected output(that what i got in Postman)

```js
[
    {
        "location": {
            "locationId": 1,
            "cityName: "London",
        }
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "locationId": 2,
            "cityName": "New York",
        },    
},
]
```

and how to get to `locationResponseRes.cityName`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that are used to console nested objects.

The best way to do so, while preserving the pretty print, is to use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))
```

where 2 is the number of spaces to use for indentation.

Another option is to use

```
const util = require('util')

console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))

// alternative shortcut
console.log(util.inspect(myObject, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
```

or

```
require('util').inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null
console.log(obj)
```

but the problem is that the nested objects after level 2 are now flattened, and this might be a problem with complex objects.

Check out [Node.js official documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-log-an-object-in-nodejs)

Comment: how can i do it with map ? something like that  const locationResponseRes =  locationResponse;      const availableLocation =availableLocationResult.map()?

Comment: I think it should work with Array as well. Did you try it?

Comment: I don't know how to do it correctly

Comment: Instead of console.log(obj), replace obj with your array. 

`console.log(array)`